# Using IsError in If-Statement

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have the following `If`-Statement:

```
If wb.Range("A1").Value = "n/a" Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "na" Then
    wb.Range("A2").Value = "-"
Else
    ...
End
```

This worked fine until `A1` contains `#NV` (the error, it's not a string) and the code gave me Error 13 (type mismatch). I tried to simply do this:

```
If IsError(wb.Range("A1").Value) = True Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "n/a" Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "na" Then
    wb.Range("A2").Value = "-"
Else
    ...
End
```

But again, type mismatch.

If I separate it like this, it works:

```
If IsError(wb.Range("A1").Value) = True Then
    wb.Range("A2").Value = "-"
ElseIf wb.Range("A1").Value = "n/a" Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "na" Then
    wb.Range("A2").Value = "-"
Else
     ...
End
```

This lead to a couple of question for me:

1. Is it possible to handle the error in some way like I tried in the second code snippet, with no `elseif` and just one `If`-statement?
2. Why does `If IsError(wb.Range("A1").Value) = True Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "n/a"` not work? Does VBA look at all `Or` conditions simultaneously and one of them returns an error, so the whole `If` statement does the same?

Comment: 1. No, I am afraid that it is not possible. `IsError(wb.Range("A1").Value) = True` is accepted, but the same row also contains `wb.Range("A1").Value = "n/a"' which cannot be evaluated by compiler...  2. Exactly because of the same reason I tried to explain above...

Comment: You could use the `Text` property of the range instead, but it is slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA does not support

> Short Circuiting

that is why `IsError(wb.Range("A1").Value) = True Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "n/a" Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "na"` is not working because it will check for all the conditions.

Better to put `wb.Range("A1").Value = "n/a" Or wb.Range("A1").Value = "na"` in elseif.

Refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/80bda3d6-7577-4570-8e28-0c62d44fd2cf/does-vba-support-shortcircuit-operators?forum=accessdev).